# После JSON.parse массив выводится в обратном порядке

Tags: javascript, массивы, json

Этот код выводит

```
console.log(response);

{"284":{"id":284},"248":{"id":248},"244":{"id":244},"241":{"id":241},"234":{"id":234}}
```

А вот этот код выводит

```
var goodsCardsArray = Object.values(JSON.parse(goodsCardsArrayJson));             
console.log(goodsCardsArray);

(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 234}
1: {id: 241}
2: {id: 244}
3: {id: 248}
4: {id: 284}
```

Как видно все элементы массива выведены в обратном порядке. Как мне сохранить порядок, так чтобы id выводились в той же последовательности что и в response?

Comment: У массивов есть метод reverse(), который, как и ожидается, меняет порядок следования элементов на обратный

Comment: А если это JSON? То как сохранить порядок?

Comment: Если нужно сохранить порядок ключей, то не используйте числа в качестве ключей. По стандарту числовые ключи в объекте всегда идут первыми, и сортируются по возрастанию, что и наблюдается в приведенном примере.

Comment: @Denis, либо вам стоит посмотреть в сторону массивов или [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) для сохранения порядка в структуре. Больше найдёте [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: Мне от json никак не уйти (

Comment: Мне интересно зачем порядок? Автор вы собираетесь как-то визуально обрабатывать файл?

Comment: Там идут посты по порядку добавления через админку. То есть не могу изменить порядок вывода постов который ввел через админку заказчик.